# Сложение в словарях Python

Tags: python

есть словарь

```
classes = {
    '10A': {
        "первый": [80, 88],
        "второй": [52, 91, 66]
    },
    '10Б': {
        'третий': [89, 77],
        'четвёртый': [82, 83, 82]
    }
}
```

как сложить сумму первого со вторым в словаре? и сумму третьего с четвёртым? и вывести результат в виде

```
'10A': 377
'10Б': 413
```

помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for k, v in classes.items():
    print(k, sum(i for j in v.values() for i in j), sep=': ')
```